# What are the Domains to allow through firewall when using GWT in a web application in production environment which is protected with in a network DMZ

Tags: java, gwt, migration, firewall, websphere-8

I am working on a web application which is built on GWT 2.1.0. We are currently moving this application to IBM WAS 8.5.5.14 servers. These new servers are behind a network DMZ, so all the outgoing network traffic need to be listed out on the firewall to allow the traffic out. GWT is trying to connect to internet for some reason and the firewall is not allowing this traffic. We see connection time out in specific GWT packages and below is the error. I would like to know list of domain names to allow through the Firewall. Thanks in Advance

*[Servlet.LOG]:.Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call:.com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)*

Comment: GWT compiles the client side code to JavaScript. There are server-side classes, too. E.g. for RPC calls. There are usually no built-in calls to some misterious servers in the internet. What are the calls blocked by your firewall? And your error message doesn't contain the full stacktrace. Sometimes the real error is hidden by some "caused by ..." exceptions. With the browser devtools you can first check, whether the calls come from browser or server side. Then start debugging or more log output to locate the sending code.

Comment: @vanje Thanks for your response, We were able to figure out this issue. GWT server side is making calls to back end APIs endpoints which are hosted in the same domain and the endpoints used to make the calls are loadbalanced URLS hence calls to Loadbalanced URLs were blocked by firewall, allowing these URLS in Firewall solved the issue.